# Why the child component isn't rendered when clicked on Link router dom with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I'd like to schieve by clicking on an individual child TaskComponent component to rout to that component sending it's is param via useParams hook. So the url changes , it means the routing works, but the component isn't rendered. Maybe it's a typo error, or the props aren't received by the child TaskComponent, so tha that the html isn't showed up.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-24-04-vp0v8m?file=/src/components/Task.js

```
// App.js

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/taskslist">
            <Taskslist Tasks={tasks} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/task/:id">
            <TaskComponent Tasks={tasks} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;

// Parent component

const Taskslist = ({ Tasks }) => {
  return (
        <div className="tasks__tasks-item">
          {Tasks.filter((task) => task.status === 0).map((task) => (
            <Task task={task} key={task.id} />
          ))}
        </div>

// Task component

import React from "react";
import { Link, generatePath } from "react-router-dom";

const Task = ({ task }) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Link to={generatePath("/task/:id", { id: task.id })}>
        <h3>{task.title}</h3>
        <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;

// Child TaskComponent

import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const TaskComponent = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const task = Tasks.filter((task) => String(task.id) === id);

  if (!task) {
    return <div>No Task</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div>
        <h3>{task.title}</h3>              //  This part isn't rendered in the browser
        <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TaskComponent;
```

I am expecting to visualize the Child TaskComponent by clicking on each individual Task component which is inside the Tasklist parent Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Array.prototype.find` instead of `Array.prototype.filter`. `.filter` returns an array instead of the `task` object you want to render.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const TaskComponent = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const task = Tasks.find((task) => String(task.id) === id);

  if (!task) {
    return <div>No Task</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div>
        <h3>{task.title}</h3>
        <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TaskComponent;
```

[image: Edit why-the-child-component-isnt-rendered-when-clicked-on-link-router-dom-with-reac]

[image]